# Select values from array subject to a condition

Tags: python, numpy, logic

I have a series X, containing N values.  I would like to select values of X subject to the condition X[i] > V.    I would think that something like:

```
Y = X[(X[:] > V)]
```

Would work.   For now, I am getting a null set, even though I know that a subset of the values in X fulfill this condition.

Am I writing this incorrectly?

Comment: Why are you using `X[:] > V` instead of just `X > V`?

Comment: You say "series", but this question is tagged `numpy`. Which is it? (though it shouldn't matter in this case)

Comment: Thanks to all, I figured it out.   BTW, meant pandas.

Answer (score 1):

The code you give is correct if you want to compare each `X[i]` with each `V[i]`. Notice

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array(range(5))
>>> v = np.array([3]*5)
>>> x[x > v]
array([4])
```

If the original is what you did want re-inspect your `x` and `v`. Notice you need not add an empty comprehension `[:]` to x, although it will not change the output. What it seems you want (from claiming this is not working) are all the x greater than *any* element of V? If so take the min of v and perform the same mask

```
x[x > np.min(v)]
```

Comment: What do you mean `Y[i]`.  That is the series he is assigning

Comment: Does he say anywhere what `V` is? It could be a scalar, it doesn't have to be another array.

Comment: good point - it was an assumption considering the claim that it was not working as OP intended